# AngularJS: iOS not showing ng-repeat values

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using AngularJS in a project in combination with the Onsen UI framework. Now in android and Chrome everything works fine. But in iOS or Safari I have some trouble showing the ng-repeat values as it should.

AngularJS:

```
Onsen.controller("catFilter", ["$scope", "$http", "store", function($scope, $http, store){
    $scope.order = [];
    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.products = [];
    $scope.categories = [];   

//GET PRODUCTS TO FILL MENU
    store.getProducts().then(function(data){
        $scope.products = data;
    })    

//GET TOTAL PRICE OF ORDER    
    $scope.getPrice = function(){
        $scope.price = 0;
            for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++)
            {
                $scope.price += $scope.order[b].aantal * $scope.order[b].price;
            }

        $scope.price = $scope.price.toFixed(2);      
        return '€ ' + $scope.price;

    } 
//MODAL ORDER OVERVIEW CHECKOUT
    $scope.modal = function(){
        modal.show();

    };
    $scope.modalhide = function(){
        modal.hide();
    }
    $scope.removeProduct = function(){

    }
 //GET AANTAL +
    $scope.getaantal = function(pid){

 }
// SEND ORDER
    $scope.sendOrder = function(order){
        $scope.placeorder = order;
        $scope.custID = document.getElementById('uname').innerHTML;
        $scope.price = 0;

            for(var b = 0; b< order.length;b++)
            {
                $scope.price += order[b].aantal * order[b].price;
            }

        $scope.price = $scope.price.toFixed(2);      
        $http.get("../api/placeorder/"+$scope.custID+"/"+$scope.price).success(function (data) {
            $scope.orderID = data;            
            for(var i = 0; i<$scope.order.length;i++){        
                $http.get("../api/placeorderdetails/"+$scope.orderID+"/"+order[i].prodid+"/"+order[i].aantal).success(function (data) {   
                    window.location = "/mserved/index1.html?username="+$scope.custID;
                    //ADD EXTRAS
                    //REDIRECT + INFORM
                    });
            }
        });
    }
//COMPOSE ORDER ADD/REMOVE/UPDATE 
    $scope.productRemove = function($event, pid){
        $scope.productid = pid;
        if($scope.order.length > 0)
        {
            for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++){
               if($scope.order[b].prodid == pid)
               {
                   if($scope.order[b].aantal > 1)
                   {
                      $scope.order[b].aantal--;
                      document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML = document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML - 1;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $scope.order.splice(b,1);
                       document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML = '+';
                       //update quantity in app UI!
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.productAdd = function($event,pname, pid, pprice) {
        $scope.pzelfdeid = -1;
        $scope.pzelfde = -1;
        $scope.prodname = pname;
        $scope.prodid = pid;
        $scope.price = pprice;
        if($scope.order.length == 0){
            $scope.order.push({prodid: $scope.prodid, prodname: $scope.prodname, aantal: 1, price: $scope.price, size: 'M', extras: ''});
            $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 1;
        }        
        else if($scope.order.length > 0){
            for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++)
            {
                if($scope.order[b].prodid == pid)
                {
                    $scope.pzelfdeid = $scope.order[b].prodid;   
                    $scope.pzelfde = b;
                }
            }
            if($scope.pzelfde > -1)
            {
                $scope.order[$scope.pzelfde].aantal++;
                $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.order[$scope.pzelfde].aantal;             
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.order.push({prodid: $scope.prodid, prodname: $scope.prodname, aantal: 1, price: $scope.price, size: 'M', extras: ''});
                $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 1;               
            }
        }

    }
}])
```

**HTML**

```
    <!-- CATEGORY 1 -->    
    <ons-template type="text/ons-template" id="lattes.html">
      <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <ons-carousel-item>  
          <ons-list>  
            <ons-list-item style="height:60px" ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | orderBy: 'category'">
                <ul style="display:inline; text-decoration:none; list-style-type:none;">
                 <li style="width: 30px; height:53px; float:left; padding:7px 0 0 5px; font-size:30px; color:gray; font-weight:thin; border-right:1px solid #ddd;"><a href="#" id="aantal" style="padding-top:10px;" ng-click="productAdd($event,product.name, product.id, product.price)">+</a></li>
                 <li style="width:65%; float:left; padding-left:5px;">
                    <ons-col width="100%" style="float:left; border-right:1px solid #F7F7F7;">
                        <div class="name" style="height:20px; margin:0; padding:0 0 0 20px; font-size:16px; ">
                          {{product.name}}
                        </div>
                    <div class="desc" style="padding:0 0 0 20px; font-size:11px; position:absolute; top:20px;">
                        {{product.description}}
                        </div>
                    </ons-col>
                 </li>
                 <li style="width: 15px; height:53px; float:right; padding:7px 4px 0 6px; text-align:right; font-size:30px; color:gray; font-weight:thin; border-left:1px solid #ddd;"><a href="#" id="aantal" style="padding-top:10px;" ng-click="productRemove($event, product.id)">-</a></li>                    
                </ul>
            </ons-list-item>
          </ons-list>
      </ons-carousel-item>
        </ons-carousel>
    </ons-template>  

    <!-- BOTTOM OVERVIEW -->    
    <ons-bottom-toolbar onclick="" style="height:60px; background-color:#5C97BF;;">
     <div style="padding-top:5px; width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
         <div style="width:25px; margin:0 auto;"><a href=""; ng-click="modal()"><img src="../images/uparrow.png"/></a></div>
        <p style="width:25%; padding-top:10px; margin-top:0; float:left; color:white; font-size:14px;">{{getQuantity()}}</p>
         <p style="width:50%; padding-top:10px; margin-top:0; float:left;text-align:center;color:white;font-size:14px;"> PERSONALIZE </p>
        <p style="width:25%;padding-top:10px; margin-top:0; float:left;text-align:right;color:white;font-size:14px;">{{getPrice()}}</p>
    </div>  
    </ons-bottom-toolbar>


<!-- MODAL CHECKOUT      -->
<ons-modal var="modal">
    <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar style="background-color:#5C97BF; height:60px;margin-bottom:40px;">
        <div class="left" style="padding:20px;"><a href=""; ng-click="modalhide()"><img src="../images/backarrow.png"/></a></div>
        <div class="right" style="padding:20px;"><a ng-click="sendOrder(order)"><i class="fa fa-send fa-fw" style="color: white"></i></a></div>
    </ons-toolbar> 
    <div style="background-color:white; width:100%; height:50px;margin-top:15px;padding:0; border-bottom:1px solid rgb(247, 247, 247);">
        <div class="left" style="padding-left:20px; width:20%; float:left;"><p>{{getQuantity()}}</p></div>
        <div class="right" style="padding-right:20px; width:20%; float:right; text-align:right;"><p>{{getPrice()}}</p></div>
    </div>

    <ons-list width="100%" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <ons-list-item class="list-item" style="height:50px;width:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:0;" ng-repeat="o in order">
        <ons-carousel swipeable style="height: 50px;" initial-index="0" auto-scroll>
          <ons-carousel-item style="height:60px;" class="list-action-item" style="width:100%;height:50px !important;">
            <ons-row style="height:50px">
              <ons-col width="13%" style="float:left; padding:0; margin:0; border-right:1px solid #F7F7F7;">
                <p style="padding:4px 0 0 18px; height:53px; margin:0;">{{o.aantal}}</p>
              </ons-col>
              <ons-col width="72%" style="float:left; border-right:1px solid #F7F7F7;">
                <div class="name" style="height:20px; margin:0; padding:0 0 0 20px; font-size:16px; ">
                    {{o.prodname}}
                </div>
                <div class="desc" style="padding:0 0 0 20px; font-size:11px; position:absolute; top:15px;">
                    {{o.extras}}
                </div>
              </ons-col>
            <ons-col width="15%" style="float:left;">
                <p style="padding:4px 0 0 18px; height:50px; margin:0;">{{o.size}}</p>
            </ons-col>
<!--            <ons-row style="height:50px">
               <ons-col  width="80%" style="float:left; padding-left:13%;">
                   <a>Skim milk</a>
                   <a>Soya milk</a>
                   <a>Extra espresso shot</a>
                   <a>Extra syrup</a>
                   <a>Whipped cream</a>
               </ons-col> 
            </ons-row>  -->
          </ons-carousel-item>
          <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-menu" style="color:white; height:60px; background:rgba(0,0,0, .6);">
              <p style="width:30%; float:right; text-align:right; padding:4px 20px 0 0; height:60px; margin:0;">remove<a ng-click="productRemove($event, o.prodid, o.prodname)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw" style="color: white"></i></a></p>              
              <p style="width:30%; float:left; padding:4px 0 0 10px; height:50px; margin:0; font-size:14px; font-weight:100; opacity:0.3;">cancel<i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-fw" style="color:white; padding-right:20px;"></i></p>
          </ons-carousel-item>            
        </ons-carousel>
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
</ons-modal>        
 </ons-template>              
<!-- MODAL CHECKOUT         -->
</div>
```

Now in the menu the `ng-repeat="product in products"` gets shown as it should BUT the `ng-repeat="o in order"` isn't showing its data. The right amount of rows (one for each o in order) is been created in the html and gets shown to the user (as you can see on the image below) but the productname and quantity etc isn't showing...? And this only in safari and iOS?

[image]
Anybody a solution to this problem?

Comment: You should use ng-options rather than ng-repeat when dealing with dropdowns.

Comment: I am not using dropdowns?